# Set Officer Powerpoint Layout to Widescreen

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

I'm making a powerpoint report in R using the `officer` package and can't figure out how to change the default layout to widescreen. The default aspect ratio is 4:3 but I'd like it widescreen (16:9). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I remember having the same issue. Solved it with a template inside read_pptx(). I cannot find the project now, but I think I used this link: https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues/218

Comment: @Bloxx I came across this link as well but wasn't sure how to write that in the read_pptx() function. I tried read_pptx(layout = "Blank") but that doesn't work. I also assume I have to reference an existing template because I'm not sure if any of the layouts offered are widescreen. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. I used this tutorial: https://github.com/JoeNoonan/r-officer-pptx-tutorial/blob/main/r-officer-pptx-tutorial.R      You read in empty pptx with desired properties which then works as a template.  (line 61-65)

Comment: You are my savior thank you so much!